# IIS pool workers : Are thread started by a worker accessible by other workers?

Tags: c#, multithreading, iis

For my ASP application, I need to start a `System.Threading.Thread` for a specific task. There must be only one instance of this thread. 
Therefore, I need to check, before starting this thread, that it is not already launch by another worker.

Will `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` retrieve all threads even started by an other app pool worker ?

Comment: Would this not be as simple as updating a static variable to say process has already started? and just check for that static variable before starting the process again?

Comment: @mahlatse To my understanding, static variable are not shared between workers of an app pool

Comment: Te could you not create a simple file that can be accessed by all your worked processes that has a field you can set to achieve your problem?

Comment: That goes through my mind but I would prefer a more 'elegant' solution before using this one. 

Comment: If you can have access to the thread, you can have access to something else, seems like a good enough solution to me, 

Comment: That the question! I'm not sure that a worker can access the thread started by an other worker.

Comment: IIS pool worker is a separate process. Threads on Windows have process isolation, i.e. processes cannot share threads, instead each process has its own set of threads which share the address space inside this process. So I don't see a way how any other worker process "can start" thread which belongs to your worker process. Consequently `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads` retrieves only threads belong to your process, which can be deduced from the method names.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov That's what I was afraid of. Do you know a way to get all thread regardless of the owner ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Like I said a thread can belong only to single process so it's not clear what you're trying to solve.

Comment: I'm trying to execute a task that must be done only one a a time. Therefore, I must ensure that this task is not being executed within a thread started by an other process. I don't want to access this thread, I only want to check its existence.

Comment: You can use `EventWaitHanndle` or `Mutex` to perform inter-process synchronization.

Comment: I didn't know it could work accros process. I'll check that asap !